# Yii2 Tabs content one page

Tags: php, yii2, tabs, pjax

in my view.php

```
<?php echo Tabs::widget([
    'items' => [
        [
            'label' => 'One',
            'content' => 'Anim pariatur cliche...',
            'active' => true
        ],
        [
            'label' => 'Two',
            'content' => 'Anim pariatur cliche...',
            'headerOptions' => [...],
            'options' => ['id' => 'myveryownID'],
        ],
?>

<div class="row" id="content1">
...some html...
</div>

<div class="row" id="content2">
...some html...
</div>
```

How to pass `id="content1"` to `Tabs::widget(['items' =>['label' => 'one', 'content' => $content1]])`

so i  can call it by id in every contents. maybe using pjax by id, but still dont know how

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

Finally i found it

[Documentation using Blocks](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/structure-views#using-blocks)

```
<?php $this->beginBlock('bank'); ?>
...content of bank details ...
<?php $this->endBlock(); ?>

<?php $this->beginBlock('education'); ?>
...content of educatinal details...
<?php $this->endBlock(); ?> 

...

<?php echo Tabs::Widget([
        'items' => [
            [
                'label' => 'Bank Detais',
                'content' => $this->blocks['bank'],
                'active' => true,
            ],
            [
                'label' => 'Educational Details',
                'content' => $this->blocks['education'],
            ],
            ...
        ]
    ]); ?>
```

Hope it helpful for others